# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with selenium 3.8.1 and gecko driver 0.19.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, exception, webdriver

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Webdriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://maps.mapmyindia.com");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("auto")).sendKeys("TCS");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("auto_geo")).click();
```

When i run this code on eclipse luna there is an error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: which firefox version you are using

Answer (score 12):

```
new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities caps);
```

is deprecated, use

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setCapability("marionette", false);
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause is the outdated Firefox version.

I upgraded the version and it works fine!

I could open the browser only setting `options.setCapability("marionette", true);`, then in the open window I upgraded through the "About Firefox" dialog. Then you have to remove the line about `marionette`.

Probably the one I had was only going to work with `marionette` while we are trying to use it with `geckodriver`, which has a different protocol. Anyone who knows more than me can confirm or deny!

Answer (score 1):

### SessionNotCreatedException

**`SessionNotCreatedException`** extends **`WebDriverException`**  and is a **`RuntimeException`** which indicates that a session could not be created.

### Possible Causes :

The possible causes of a new session not getting created are as follows :

- Compatibility issues between **`JDK`**, **`Selenium`**, **`WebDriver`** and **`Web Browser`** versions.
- Accessing the same port number by `GeckoDriver` or `Marionette` by the new session which previous session have't released yet.
- Lack of access to `CPU`
- Lack of `Physical Memory`
- Lack of `Swap Memory`
- Lack of `Disc Cache`
- Lack of `Network Bandwidth`
- Presence of `OS chores` within the system.

### Code Block :

I don't see any coding issue in your code block as such.

### Solution :

The simple solution would be as follows :

- Always use the latest released version of JDK (Java SE 9.0.1), Selenium-Java client (v3.8.1), WebDriver variant (GeckoDriver v0.19.1) and Web Browser (Firefox Quantum Browser).
- If the base version of the Web Browser is too old consider uninstalling the Browser through Revo Uninstaller and install a recent released GA version of Firefox Browser.
- Always use quit() in the tearDown() method so that the webdriver and the webclient both are properly destroyed.
- Clean the Project Workspace from your IDE before and after executing your Test Suite.
- Clear the Browser Cache before and after the execution of your Tests.
- Use CCleaner tool regularly to wipe away the OS chores.
- Execute your Test.

Answer (score 0):

You should add capabilities for firefox. Please modify your code as follows

```java
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");

 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

 capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
 capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
 capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
 capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);

 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

 driver.get("https://maps.mapmyindia.com");
```

If your windows is `windows_nt` then put `windows_nt` instead of `windows`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i solved the issue by adjusting my java version to 1.8.1, thank you again for your support.

Comment: it is just opening firefox (version 48.0), but not navigate to that site

Comment: Please update your firefox to latest one. Then it will be okay and run properly

Comment: now error in platform name TypeError: Given platformName [object String] "windows", but current platform is [object String] "windows_nt", and i change the platform name to windows_nt but it is not working.

Comment: Setting FirefoxOptions also did the trick:

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions;
firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", false);