# Selenium: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, firefox, vps, katalon-studio

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2FjO.png)

I'm setting Katalon tests on my **VPS: os.name: Linux, os.arch: amd64*, os.version: '4.9.0-6-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'**

**I've put geckodriver and firefox in my usr/local/bin, by "sudo cp".**

My **Firefox version is 66.0.5**.

And here is how I am running tests:

```
~/autotests/Katalon/katalon --args -noSplash -runMode=console -projectPath="/home/andrii_nyvchyk/autotests/tellbot-autotest/mega-test/mega-test.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/Mega test" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Firefox (headless)" -consoleLog
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Is something wrong? Are you getting some error messages? What happens when you execute the command?

Comment: @MateMrše i've got this error: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Also I've added a screenshot.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107055/unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-with-selenium-3-8-1-and-gecko-driv

Comment: What geckodriver version are you using?

Comment: @MateMrše I've updated everything. I am using the latest geckodriver v.24.